# Why I can't POST DATA using ReactJs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I'm having a bit of trouble why I can't properly POST my data to my `MySQL-database`, I tried to check the endpoints but I'm still having an error.

```
publicRequest.jsx

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:4000/api/"

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL
})
```

FrontSide

AddQuestion.jsx

```
const [answerData, setAnswerData] = useState({
 p1_question: "",
 p1_question_order: "",
 type: questionType,
 toggle: "0",
 category: []
})



const handleSubmitQuestion = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

try {
  await publicRequest.post('student_q_1', answerData);
  console.log("Success");
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

This is my front side, the handleSubmitQuestion sends the data to my endpoint.

This is the image sample I console.log()

[image: Sample Data I post]

BackendSide

index.js

```
app.use('/api/student_q_1', studentQuestion1)


app.listen(4000, () =>{
console.log(`Website is running at port http://localhost:${4000}`)
})
```

this is my router.js

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
const { p1_question, p1_question_order, type, toggle, category } = req.body;
const query = "INSERT INTO 1_question_student (part_1_question, part_1_question_order, 
type, toggle, category) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try {
  const [rows, field] = await connection.execute(query, [
    p1_question,
    p1_question_order,
    type,
    toggle,
    category
  ]);
  res.status(200).json(rows);
} catch (error) {
  res.status(404).json(error);
}
})
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: I get an `error of 404`

Comment: 404 (page not found) means you send it to a wrong url

Comment: Or your code caught the error. Do you have additional error message?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it,

it seems like my query is not properly stated

```
 const { p1_question, p1_question_order, type, toggle, category } = req.body;
    const query = "INSERT INTO 1_question_student (`p1_question`, `p1_question_order`, type, toggle, category) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
  
    try {
      const [rows, field] = await connection.execute(query, [
        p1_question,
        p1_question_order,
        type,
        toggle,
        category
      ]);
      res.status(200).json(rows);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(404).json(error);
    }
  }
```